# PHP how to loop through an array and grab specific parts

Tags: php, arrays, list, unordered

Ok so im trying to grab a single part of an array, the array is the return for some stats there can be up to 8 players in the server, the data i get is like this

```
Array (
 [0] => 1
 [1] => Player1
 [2] =>
 [3] => 1
 [4] => 0
 [5] => 0
 [6] => 0
 [7] => 0
 [8] => 1
 [9] => Player2
 [10] =>
 [11] => 1
 [12] => 0
 [13] => 0
 [14] => 0
 [15] => 0
)
```

so that is the return for 2 players, as i said it can be up to 8, anyway i am trying to just grab the player names and im not sure how to go about it ( Player1 , Player2  ) is the only data i need, any help is appreciated, it always returns 8 pieces of data per player never more never less if that makes it easier

(sorry for bad english)

Comment: How do you build this array? maybe by fixing how you build the array it will be easier to manipulate it!

Comment: Are those other numbers strings or integers?

Answer (score 2):

You want to get all items that are not `''` (assuming empty string), `0` or `1` (assuming integers here):

```
$playerNames = array_diff($array, array('', 0, 1));
```

If you more specifically know what the *format* of the array actually is, you can also create some little "parser":

```
$playerSize = 8;
$playerFields = array('_1', 'name', '_3', '_4', '_5', '_6', '_7', '_8');
$players = array_chunk($array, $playerSize);

foreach($players as &$player)
{
    $player = (object) array_combine($playerFields, $player);
}
unset($player);
```

This does parse `$array` into another array `$players` that contains one object per each player. Each object has the `name` property now:

```
printf("%d Player(s):\n", count($players));

foreach($players as $i => $player)
{
    printf("#%d: %s\n", $player->name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the return type, I would restructure the array being returned either into an Object or an array of arrays where each sub array contains all of the information for one player.

I you don't have control over the return type and the Player's name is always in the second position within the return array you can use a while loop to iterate over the array. Use a counter starting at 1 and then increment the counter by 8 each time through the loop. For example:

```
$i= 1;
while ($i < count($return_var)) {
    $name = $return_var[$i];
    // do something w/ name
    $i += 8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the array you pasted is called `$array` and the values of the places without players are always numeric (like your example), this code will work:

```
$players = array();
foreach($array as $player){
    if(!empty($player) && !is_numeric($player){
        $players[]=$player;
    }
}

var_dump($players);
```